# Adding drag and drop connectors in react-konva

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I'm using react-konva and I'm trying to add connector lines between circles by dragging from one circle and then dropping it on the other circle to be connected.
So far I have tried it by clicking the circles to create a line between them and made it draggable as a group. Here's the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dubinsky-2zqov?file=/src/DragNDrop/DropStage.js). Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you explain what is not working as you expect please ? As far as I can see from your demo what you have described as the desired result is working.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Instead of clicking on the circles, I want to drag a line from circleA and drop it on circleB to connect them together

Comment: I'll leave this here in case anyone is looking for an answer in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498329/how-to-connect-2-objects-using-a-line-using-konvajs-in-vuejs

Comment: See my question + self answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858947/how-to-use-event-listeners-efficiently-when-there-are-potentially-very-many-shap) which draws lines between shapes as the user drags and 'jumps' the connecting line to an overlapped  shape when that happens.  Maybe you can adapt it.